# How to sort by comparing with each characters in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

Sorry, I have a question about sort data.
I don't know how to sort each characters , I just sort by first characters like following image.
How can I sort characters in each section array.
Thanks.

[image]

```
var cityCollation: UILocalizedIndexedCollation? = nil
var sectionsCityArray = [[City]]()
var cityArray:[City] = [City]() //cityArray is my original data that is not sorting 

func configureSectionCity() { 

    cityCollation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current()

    let sectionTitlesCount = cityCollation!.sectionTitles.count

    var newSectionsArray = [[City]]()

    for _ in 0..<sectionTitlesCount {
        let array = [City]()
        newSectionsArray.append(array)
    }

    for bean in cityArray {
        let sectionNumber = cityCollation?.section(for: bean, collationStringSelector: #selector(getter: City.name))
        var sectionBeans = newSectionsArray[sectionNumber!]

        sectionBeans.append(bean)
        newSectionsArray[sectionNumber!] = sectionBeans
    }

  sectionsCityArray = newSectionsArray

  }
```

Comment: What about using `array.sort` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `City` object has a `name` property and you want the order `q001`, `q002`, `q004`, `q005`, `q010`, `q012` you could use

```
newSectionsArray[sectionNumber!] = sectionBeans.sorted { $0.name.localizedStandardCompare($1.name) == .orderedAscending }
```

`localizedStandardCompare` requires the `Foundation` framework